# PyMongo .find() Special Characters

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

So I have set up a database in MongoDB and a majority of documents contain a special code which can begin with a * and finish with a #. When I use the following query on the MongoDb command line, it works fine but when I try to use it in a python script, it doesn't work.

```
cursor = collect.find({$and:[{"key":/.*\*.*/},{"key":/.*\#.*/}]})
```

I think the problem lies with the # in the query but when I wrap it in " ", it doesn't work.

```
cursor = collect.find({'$and':[{"key":'/.*\*.*/'},{"key":'/.*\#.*/'}]})
```

Please note that I put ' ' around $and and the first expression to match because syntax errors appear when I attempt to run it.

Thanks

Comment: can you just give sample of your documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to query using a regular expression, then you have to create a Python regular expression object. Note that in this case the string should not be surrounded by `//`.

```
import re
cursor = collect.find({'$and':[{"key":re.compile('.*\*.*')},{"key":re.compile('.*\#.*')}]})
```

Alternatively, you can use the `$regex` operator

```
cursor = collect.find({'$and':[{"key": {"$regex": '.*\*.*'}},{"key": {"$regex": '.*\#.*'}}]})
```